# Is it possible to install mono in an apache server that also runs Django?

Tags: asp.net, django, apache, mono

I'm pretty new to apache web hosting as my experience has been mainly in writing ASP .Net hosted on Windows boxes.  I'm starting a new project for a client soon and on their Fedora web server they already have 3 other websites running under the Django framework on Apache.

I'm looking to write this new application in ASP .Net and therefore am looking into installing mono on the server so I can run it.  I've had a look through the mono documentation but I don't want to start installing it on their server in case it messes up the existing sites running on Django.  Can anyone give me any advice on this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Usually Django is deployed with `mod_wsgi` and ASP.NET with `mod_mono`. These mods can coexist together, if you know how to configure them.

Comment: Thanks, suppose I need to read up on Apache architecture a bit more